# how to display a message with two buttons in python qt designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, designer

i am constructing a little minesweeper clone, and i have a function here for the event that the user clicks onto the bomb the button displays "boom" but also i want to add a function where something like a menu pops up prompting the user that they have lost, and provide them with two buttons one to continue on, the other asking to start a new game.

```
def buttonClickedkill(self):
    # sender() tells us who caused the action to take place
    clicked = self.sender()
    #letter=clicked.text()  # the buttons have the letters on them
    #print(f"Button -{letter}- was clicked!")
    # 1) Disable the button
    clicked.setEnabled(False)
    clicked.setText("boom")
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
```

so then i want to add another function where a pop up thing comes and says something like:

> sorry you struck a bomb and died!
>
> continue?    New Game!

with "continue" and "new game" being two buttons
i have a new game function and all.

also could you please provide me with the necessary script that would close the window as soon as one of the buttons is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact use case of a [`QMessageBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QMessageBox.html). For example:

```
reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Title', 'You lost! Continue?')
```

This line makes a window pop up and blocks the main GUI until the user clicks a button. Since I chose a `QMessageBox.question`, the default buttons are "yes" and "no". You can ask the `reply` variable whether the user clicked on the "yes" (`QMessageBox.Yes`) or "no" (`QMessageBox.No`) button.

Working example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, 
                             QMessageBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, 
                             QWidget)


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.button = QPushButton(parent=self, text="Click Me!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked_kill)
        self.text = QLabel(parent=self, text='')

        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.text)

    def button_clicked_kill(self):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Title', 'You lost! Continue?')
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.text.setText('User answered yes')
        if reply == QMessageBox.No:
            self.text.setText('User answered no')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()
    gui = MyApp()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which generates:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how you did it, but i cannot thank you enough! i was stuck for two hours and allready watched a bunch of Indian video's on Youtube, i even built and imported a different class created almost an entirely new design and stuff, i cant believe it was that that easy. thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Remember, most "common" GUI features like text boxes, progress bars, tabs, etc have some sort of ready implementation on Qt. Try digging a bit more in the (admittedly confusing and incomplete) documentation when you run into issues.

Comment: @yesitsme also consider the original C++ docs, which are more comprehensive and much more readable than the pyside ones; even if it's C++ oriented, function names, arguments and returned data types are the same in 99% of the cases, and you can check for inconsistencies from the pyside/[pyqt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/sip-classes.html) docs or using `help()` in a python shell. Finally, start by studying the base classes (QObject/QWidget) and from there read each inherited class (eg: see all classes that inherit from QDialog, which in turn inherits from QWidget).

Comment: thank you once again, your answer was absolutely professional.